# How to solve $z^{1995}+z^{-1995}$ if $1+z+z^2=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know this is high school basic math, but please bear with me:

$z^2=-z$, so the $z_1=-1$ or $z_2=0$.

Now, when I put the solutions in $z^{1995}+z^{-1995}$ equation:
 1. $z_1=-1 \implies (-1)^{1995}+(-1)^{-1995}=(-1)+(-1)=-2$.
 2. $z_2=0 \implies 0^{1995}+0^{-1995}=0+$(not defined)$=0.$

But the solution is $z^{1995}+z^{-1995}$=**2**

What did I miss?

Comment: Is it possible you have $1+z+z^2=0$? These types of problems often exploit roots of unity.

Comment: I bet the question was $1 + z + z^2 = 0$.  That gives you $(z-1)(1+z+z^2) = z^3 - 1 =0$ and $z^3 = 1$ and there are three such complex numbers that do that $1, \alpha = e^{\frac 23 \pi i}, \alpha^2 = e^{\frac 43\pi i}$.  And it can't be $z=1$.  So $z^3 =1$ so $z^{1995}=z^{3*665} = 1$ and $z^{-1995}= (z^{3*665})^{-1}=1^{-1} = 1$ and so the answer is $2$.

Comment: @fleablood me when solving this problem: "that question doesn't make sense to me. let me answer a different question i made up."

Comment: For what it's worth:  You did the problem, as typed correctly.  $1+z+z^2 = 1\implies z(z+1) = 0\implies z = -1, 0$ and $0^{-1995}$ is undefined while $(-1)^{1995} = (-1)^{-1995} = -2$.  ... but I'm sure someone made a typo and it was supposed to be $1+z+z^2 = 0$.

Comment: Well, okay... but the problem let  $1 + z + z^2 + ..... + z^{k-1} = 0$ is such a *COMMON* problem and such a useful, one, and it *is* the answer given by the book and the question as typed is kind of pointless and a different answer.... we are almost certainly correct.

Comment: @Integrand In the exercise book there is written $1+z+z^2=1$. So the authors made a mistake and not me :) (I triple checked)

Answer (score 2):

If $1+z+z^2=0$, then $z= e^{2\pi i/3}$, $e^{-2\pi i /3}$. This is because $z$ is a root of $z^3-1=0$ not equal to $1$. Note that $z^3=z^{-3}=1$ and $3|1995$.

Comment: I think one of those $2$ was meant to be a $4$ or a $-2$.